# How to conditional remove a property from an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface Info<
  BodyType = undefined,
  QueryStringType = undefined,
  PathParamType = undefined,
  ResponseType = undefined
> {
  request: {
    queryStrings: QueryStringType;
    pathParameters: PathParamType;
    body: BodyType;
  };
  response: ResponseType;
}

type InfoExtend = Info<{ name: string }>;

const a1: InfoExtend = {
  request: {
    body: { name: "a" },
  },
};
```

I have an `Info` type, which is an interface for describing an endpoint, and the `InfoExtend` is the actual type for an endpoint implementation.

The problem is, the `a1` has a type error:

> Type '{ body: { name: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ queryStrings: undefined; pathParameters: undefined; body: { name: string; }; }': queryStrings, pathParameters(2739)

I get it, because `queryStrings` and `pathParameters`. are not optional

The question is, can I make the `body`, `queryStrings` and `pathParameters` associated with the generic, such that, if I pass `BodyType` generic, then `body` is in `Info.request.body`, if I do not pass `BodyType`, then `Info.request` should not have any error, and it must contain 1 of the 3 (body/queryString/pathParams)

[**Playground link:**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhgewDwChnIBCmAJgJ4AqZADigLzICuIJEMoEJANPsgIqNoZAMpgooAOZVayBs1bsQnHgQAKcMAAt1UOAFtp9JizYduvAEoQAztUwhrEQ7OMKzuAHzIA3rygQAR0FrMAAuH14CIKFRcRAJa3CBGLFJQwBuSORqDW04XT0ISChE5HUtHX0MrIAjUjJw4nJqggBfTIJ-W3tHcKtuhycaCEzW3FwwYbQMTABRAA9IFhd0LGxvZBB9CHCQuIlkVo9M3AQesGQ4AEZw1bnFiGWGX07A4LCIggI68nCNrcK4QARHAgYcVODcO0gA)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this making the missing fields as `optional`:

```js
interface Info<
  BodyType = undefined,
  QueryStringType = undefined,
  PathParamType = undefined,
  ResponseType = undefined
> {
  request: {
    queryStrings?: QueryStringType;
    pathParameters?: PathParamType;
    body: BodyType;
  };
  response?: ResponseType;
}

type InfoExtend = Info<{ name: string }>;

const a1: InfoExtend = {
  request: {
    body: { name: "a" },
  },
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhgewDwChnIBCmAJgJ4AqZADigLzICuIJEMoEJANPsgIqNoZAMpgooAOZVayBs1bsQnHgQAKcMAAt1UOAFtp9JizYduvAEoQAztUwhrEQ7OMKzuAHzIA3rygQAR0FrMAAuH14CIKFRcRAJawB%20cIEYsUlDAG5I5GoNbThdPQhIKCTw9S0dfSycgCNSMnDiclqCAF9sgn9be0dk5CtehycaCGz23FwwMbQMTABRAA9IFhd0LGxvZBB9CHCQuIlkdo9s3AQ%20sGQ4AEZwjcWViDWGX27A4LCIggIG8nC212xXCACI4KCTioobhOkA)

Comment: Thanks, but they are still there in the final type, if you type a1.request., then `queryStrings` will pop up, but I do not need them there if I do not pass their generic type. Is it possible with the current TS?

Comment: But at some point don't you need `queryString`, `pathParameters`, and `response`?

Now they are optional fields which mean, they are not required for `request`.
(Maybe I misunderstood your comment)